# Firebase - how to attach image's downloadUrl to its own metadata?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, metadata, firebase-storage

When we upload an image to the firebase storage, is there a way to attach that image's download url to its own metadata? From my understanding, it seems that you can only get the download url after you have called the:

```
ref.putBytes(byteArray, metadata);
```

So effectively, you can't have the downloadUrl until you have uploaded your image. And since your metadata is attached at the time when you upload your image, there doesn't seem to be a way to have your downloadUrl included in your metadata.

Please let me know if there's a way around this.

**Why I want to attach downloadUrl to my metadata**
Just a bit of extra context. I want to have my downloadUrl attached to my image's metadata, so that I will be able to use the cloud function to pass these informations to the firebase database. I want to do it this way instead of uploading the downloadUrl to the firebase storage separately, so that I can ensure that the storage and database are always synced up. We can't have a situation where only the image was uploaded, or only the downloadUrl was uploaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the metadata for a storage reference at any time by calling [`StorageReference.updateMetadata`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.html#updateMetadata(com.google.firebase.storage.StorageMetadata)) on it.

Comment: Thank you! You are a life saver.